# @Controller no longer using spring.data.rest.base-path variable for REST URL for @RequestMapping

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-rest, applicationcontext

I created a `@RestController` for all `@Entity` objects the REST URL is being set correctly using `spring.data.rest.base-path` variable set in `application.peroperties` as `/api` but for a `@RequestMapping("someEndpoint")` it is not using the variable.

Example

For `@Entity` class User the REST endpoint is located at:

```
`http://localhost:8081/api/users'
```

But when I try to access `someEndpoint`:

```
'http://localhost:8081/api/someEndpoint'
```

I get a response of:

Response Status

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Body

```
"timestamp":1461267817272,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/api/someEndpoint"}
```

Instead the endpoint of the REST service is located at

```
'http://localhost:8081/someEndpoint'
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Controller class

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("someEndpoint")
    public Stuff runSomething(
            @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) String id)
```

What am I missing in my configuration?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`spring.data.rest.base-path` is for Spring Data REST, which expose Repository to outside by REST with HATEOAS not for spring context.

What you want is `server.context-path` for Spring MVC stuff.

Check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) for full properties.

Comment: Thank you.  I have a mixture of Spring Data REST objects as well so I will be using both.